# How to propagate npm script command line arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-scripts

My `package.json` has few scripts defined in this manner.

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "scripts": {
    "standard": "./node_modules/.bin/standard",
    "lint": "npm run standard",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix"
  }
}
```

When I execute `$ npm run lint:fix` I find that the argument `--fix` does not propagate to `./node_modules/.bin/standard`. This is the output that I get.

```
bash-3.2$ npm run lint:fix

> project@0.0.1 lint:fix /path/to/my/project
> npm run lint -- --fix

> project@0.0.1 lint /path/to/my/project
> npm run standard "--fix"

> project@0.0.1 standard /path/to/my/project
> standard

standard: Use JavaScript Standard Style (http://standardjs.com)
standard: Run `standard --fix` to automatically fix some problems.
  /path/to/my/project/data/someFile.js:38:34: Extra semicolon.

npm ERR! Darwin 16.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "standard" "--fix"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

Here there's an error because `--fix` argument didn't propagate correctly.

Well, my question is not around linting or standardJs. I would like to know how to get the arguments propagate correctly till the top level script.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is what I found after sweating a lot on this issue. (It is very silly, though).

The error was caused not because the argument didn't propagate. Instead, it was because the `--fix` flag in `standard` doesn't auto-fix the semicolon issues during linting.

In the given set of scripts (in the question). The argument successfully propagated. Therefore, that's the way to propagate arguments till the top level script.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need a double `-- --` in your npm script.

Your `lint:fix` script should be: `"npm run lint --fix"`

Comment: Hi @edwarddamato, I think double `-- --` is required. Coz, the first set of hyphens is the separator between npm script command and the arguments (that needs to be passed to script) while the second set is argument itself.